# How to access app data properties in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm currently migrating to Vue 3, I used to be able to access properties in the old vue 2 app like this:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler';
...

const app = createApp({
  // el: 'app', // removed
  data() {
    const results = ...;

    return {
      results,
      ...
    };
  },
  ...
});

// added for vue 3
app.mount('app')

const { results } = app

console.log(results) // is undefined
```

..but now I can't, and inspecting the app object I'm unable to find data properties. Also, I'm curious if this has changed and best practice.

The app is rendering on the page, but I also need to access properties of the app for additional stuff but I'm unable to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Then you can access your data in Vue 3 over the `vm` object, like in Vue 2.

But now you have to get your `vm` object from the `mount()` function, not from  `createApp()`

v2

```
var vm = new Vue({...})
vm.myData =
```

v3

```
var app = Vue.createApp({})
app.myData = // this does not work

var vm = app.mount('#app')
vm.myData =  // this works
```

Be careful with destructing your data, it could lose the reactivity.
Use [`toRef`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-utilities.html#toref) and [`toRefs`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-utilities.html#torefs) to keep the reactivity.

```js
const { createApp, ref, toRef } = Vue;

const App = { 
  data() {
    return {
      title: 'My App'
    }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
console.log(`app.title: ${app.title}`) // --> undefined
const vm = app.mount('#app')
console.log(`vm.title: ${vm.title}`) // --> My App

// Be careful with destructing your data, it could lose the reactivity.
console.log('-- Reactivity is lost ---') 
var { title } = vm;
console.log(`title: ${title}`) 
title = 'My new Title'
console.log("title = 'My new Title'") 
console.log(`title: ${title}`) // --> 'My new Title'
console.log(`vm.title: ${vm.title}`) // --> My App

// Be careful with destructing your data, it could lose the reactivity.
console.log('--- Reactivity works ---') 
const title2 = toRef(vm, 'title');
console.log(`title2.value: ${title2.value}`) // --> My App
title2.value = 'My new Title 2'
console.log("title2.value = 'My new Title 2'") 
console.log(`title2.value: ${title2.value}`) // --> My new Title 2
console.log(`vm.title: ${vm.title}`) // --> 'My new Title 2'
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
{{title}}
</div>

<!-- include VueJS first -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```